# Is the present participle incorrect in sentences like "I will run one mile to reach my target, grabbing him"?

Tags: present-participles

Is it okay (in terms of usage) to use present participle clause for an action that follows another action as a result?

For instance, the following sentence seems correct to me:

> The bomb will explode, sending shrapnel everywhere.

Yet the following sentence does not correct at all to me:

> I will run one mile to reach my target, grabbing him.

I don't know how I feel about this sentence, I think it feels fine:

> The cat leaped into the air, landing in the river.

This sentence feels pretty wrong:

> I noticed my target, shooting until I hit him.

But this sentence feels fine:

> The man took off from one end of the street, reaching the other side just in time.

And then obviously this sentence feels not great:

> I will live a good life, dying.

But then this sentence feels fine:

> I will live a good life, dying when it reaches its conclusion.

What's the differentiator here? Are my feelings correct?

Comment: I agree with your feelings. I don't know the technical reasons why, though.

Comment: The issue is, I think, whether there's a causal relationship: the bomb exploding causes the sending of shrapnel, but you running doesn't cause you to grab him.

Comment: "I will run one mile to reach my target, grabbing him when I get there" is OK IMO, so it quite possibly is to do with causal relationships, or just the closeness of the relationship.